# PHP Failed To Send Data To SOAP Server

Tags: php, soap

My Client gave me URL for SOAP purpose, so I can send data directly to their server. and when I open the URL, it gives me this XML :

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:element name="RegisterApplication">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="oEnt" type="tns:DataCustomer"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="DataCustomer">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PartnerID" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Datetime" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CustomerName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EmailCustomer" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CustomerAddress" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CustomerNumber1" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CustomerNumber2" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SubmissionID" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ListingID" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SellerName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SellerNumber" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EmailSeller" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SellerAddress" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Product" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VehicleType" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Year" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Funding" type="s:decimal"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LinkIklan" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ZipCode" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="City" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Kelurahan" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Kecamatan" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CustDateOfBirth" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MonthlyIncome" type="s:decimal"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Brand" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Tenor" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Installment" type="s:decimal"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ImageIDCustomer" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ImageStnkNoticePajak" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="RegisterApplicationResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RegisterApplicationResult" type="tns:DataCustomerRespond"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="DataCustomerRespond">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Status" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Notes" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="RegisterApplicationSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RegisterApplication"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="RegisterApplicationSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RegisterApplicationResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="APISoap">
<wsdl:operation name="RegisterApplication">
<wsdl:input message="tns:RegisterApplicationSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:RegisterApplicationSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="APISoap" type="tns:APISoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="RegisterApplication">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/RegisterApplication" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="APISoap12" type="tns:APISoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="RegisterApplication">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/RegisterApplication" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="API">
<wsdl:port name="APISoap" binding="tns:APISoap">
<soap:address location="http://example.com/apidigital/api.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="APISoap12" binding="tns:APISoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://example.com/apidigital/api.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

and here's my PHP code :

```
<?
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/api.asmx?wsdl");
$params = array ( "PartnerID" => "17000000",
                  "Datetime" => "2017-04-11T00:24:59",
                  "CustomerName" => "Robson",
                  "EmailCustomer" => "robson@email.com",
                  "CustomerAddress" => "Somewhere On Earth",
                  "CustomerNumber1" => "08100000000",
                  "CustomerNumber2" => "08380000000",
                  "SubmissionID" => "KOM000000",
                  "ListingID" => "FB120374",
                  "SellerName" => "",
                  "SellerNumber" => "",
                  "EmailSeller" => "",
                  "SellerAddress" => "",
                  "Product" => "Motor",
                  "VehicleType" => "Honda",
                  "Year" => "1995",
                  "Funding" => "2000000",
                  "LinkIklan" => "www.example.com/21938",
                  "ZipCode" => "15322",
                  "City" => "Serpong",
                  "Kelurahan" => "Cisauk",
                  "Kecamatan" => "Sampora",
                  "CustDateOfBirth" => "1971-02-16",
                  "MonthlyIncome" => "9000000",
                  "Brand" => "Honda",
                  "Tenor" => "12",
                  "Installment" => "318500",
                  "ImageIDCustomer" => "https://example.com",
                  "ImageStnkNoticePajak" => "https://example.com" );

$response = $client->RegisterApplication($params);
print_r($response);
?>
```

my php always failed to submit the data to the server using SOAP. it always gives me this error :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [RegisterApplicationResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Status] => 99
            [Notes] => Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        )

)
```

did I miss something in my parameter? why PHP can't send the data inside array to SOAP server?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You do not match the expected request.

The `RegisterApplication` operation is waiting for a `RegisterApplication` element as parameter which contains a `oEnt` property which is of type `DataCustomer`. So normally, you should have an array with the first key `oEnt` which would point to your current array `$params` containing all your customer data.

If you don't want to waste time, you should consider using a WSDL to php generator such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project which generates all the required classes in order to construct the request parameters, send the request then finally handle the response.